# How to create a dynamic Material UI Icon Atom in StoryBook and React TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, storybook

I am using **StoryBook** with **React**, **TypeScript**, and **Material UI**. I want to create an `Icon Atom` that behaves dynamically so that it can render the icon which I want to pass in as a `prop`.

Right Now, I am using the below-mentioned approach, but there are some problems with this.

1. I am unable to change the Icon for a particular story. That's not the dynamic behavior I want.
2. I also want to pass in some `props` such as `fontSize` and `color` to my `Material UI Icon` so that it can use them to render differently based on the value of `props`.

I want my component to behave according to the above two points. Please help !!

`Icon.stories.tsx` File

```js
import React from "react";
import { ComponentStory, ComponentMeta } from "@storybook/react";
import MyIcon from "./Icon";
import AccessTimeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AccessTime";
import PersonOutlineIcon from "@mui/icons-material/PersonOutline";

export default {
  title: "Atoms/MyIcon",
  component: MyIcon,
  argTypes: {
    color: {
      options: [
        "primary",
        "secondary",
        "warning",
        "error",
        "info",
        "success",
        "action",
      ],
      control: { type: "radio" },
    },
    fontSize: {
      options: ["small", "medium", "large"],
      control: { type: "radio" },
    },
  },
} as ComponentMeta<typeof MyIcon>;

const Template: ComponentStory<typeof MyIcon> = (args) => <MyIcon {...args} />;

export const Clock = Template.bind({});
Clock.args = {
  fontSize: "medium",
  color: "primary",
  materialIcon: <AccessTimeIcon />,
};

export const Person = Template.bind({});
Person.args = {
  fontSize: "large",
  color: "warning",
  materialIcon: <PersonOutlineIcon />,
};
```

`Icon.tsx` File

```js
import React from "react";
import type { IconProps } from "@mui/material/Icon";

interface MyIconProps extends IconProps {
  materialIcon: React.ReactElement;
}

const MyIcon = ({ materialIcon, fontSize, color }: MyIconProps) => {
  return <>{materialIcon}</>;
};
export default MyIcon;
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a library like [material-icons-react](https://github.com/logtrace/material-icons-react) which provides a react component that you can render with custom props.

```
import MaterialIcon, {colorPalette} from 'material-icons-react';

<MaterialIcon icon="dashboard" />

// different sizes
<MaterialIcon icon="dashboard" size='large' />
<MaterialIcon icon="dashboard" size={100} />

// colours
<MaterialIcon icon="dashboard" color={colorPalette.amber._200} />
<MaterialIcon icon="dashboard" color={colorPalette.amber.A700} />
<MaterialIcon icon="dashboard" color='#7bb92f' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is including the material icons via Google Web Fonts script.

Add this to your html entry point:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then you can use the `material-icons` class name and put the icon name inside the element:

```
<span class="material-icons">access_time_icon</span>
```

You can put this rendering in you Icon component and pass any styling props you want.

Note that if you use other icon variants, e.g. outlined, you need to add a separate font for each variant and use a different class like `material-icons-outlined`.

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<span class="material-icons">access_time_icon</span>
```

Comment: This is not useful to me as it will work on the browser. But for some reason, the icons rendered using this method do not show up on storybook canvas at all. Even if they do, it's the text that gets displayed instead of icons. My goal is to make it appear on the storybook canvas.

Comment: i believe storybook has its own html file where you need to inject the font as well. not sure what you mean by "it will work on the browser".